# TableDataAdapter.update() and TableDataAdapter.Fill() it take long time

Tags: mysql, vb.net

have table with 200 columns, and when try to fill or update apporx. (15000) rows using the following:-

```
TableDataAdapter.update(DataTable)
TableDataAdapter.Fill(Datatable)
```

it take around 8 mins and some cases stacked and not complete the process

then tried to use the below code for select command to fill

```
        Dim My_Trans as SQLTransaction
        Dim My_Table as new DataTable
        Dim My_SQLDataAdapter as new SqlDataAdapter
        Dim My_BindingSource as new BindingSource

        conn.Open()
        My_Trans = conn.BeginTransaction()

        myqry = "Select * From My_Table"
        My_SQLDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(myqry, conn)
 
        Try
            My_SQLDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Transaction = My_Trans
            My_BindingSource.DataSource = My_Table
            DataGridView1.DataSource = My_BindingSource    '(<----- her is take long time)

            My_Trans.Commit()
        Catch ex As Exception
            My_Trans.Rollback()
        End Try
        conn.Close()
```

but still take the same time , even for update command too, when tracking found the time taking in (DataGridView1.DataSource = My_BindingSource)

any advise please how speed up fill and update process?

many thanks in advance

---

I have tried as follow:-

1- Adding Class

```
 Namespace DataSet1TableAdapters
    Partial Public Class Table1TableAdapter
        Public Function CreartTransaction() As Data.IDbTransaction
        Try
            Dim cmd As SqlCommand
            Dim oConnection = me.CommandCollection(0).Connection
                if oConnection.State = ConnectionState.Open 
                    Else
                   oConnection.Open()
                End If
            Dim oTrans As SqlTransaction = oConnection.BeginTransaction()
            For Each cmd In me.CommandCollection
                cmd.Connection = oConnection
                cmd.Transaction = oTrans
            Next
        Return oTrans
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
        End Function
    End Class
End Namespace
```

2- then on from added this code to save changes (Delete/Add/Modified):-

```
 Dim oTrans As SqlTransaction = Table1TableAdapter.CreartTransaction
 me.Table1TableAdapter.Transaction = oTrans
 try
     me.Table1TableAdapter.Update(me.DataSet1.Table1) (<----- Here when Have new rows not work and stop process without any error message)
     oTrans.Commit
 Catch ex As Exception
     oTrans.Rollback
 End Try
```

if Modified or deleted rows everything works fine, but if new rows added stacked and stop process without error message,

any explanation why ?

many thanks

Comment: Just to clarify because you're question and the code comments don't tally.  Is it the actually the fill()/Update() methods taking the time, or is it binding the DataGridView as per the comment?  You code also makes little sense; you don't appear to be doing anything with My_Table before binding and why on earth would your wrap a select query in a db transaction?  Is this the actual code you're using?

Comment: need to fill around 15000 to 20000 rows, and table has 207 columns

Comment: why load 20k rows to the gridview would be unusable to the user anyway,   that's what server side pagination is all about.

Comment: yes when i use DataAdapter.Fill(Datatable) it take 8 mins but here note sure the adapter fill taking time or datagridview binding, but when go to other code then can track and found the time in datagridview binding, and I use the query to fill sqldataadapter only to use transaction, the datasetadapter doesnt have option to set transaction due to not has adapter.Selectcommand or adapter.updatecommand

Comment: yes need to load 20K rows at the beginning only then there is a filter tools works with My_DatatableBindingsource.Filter for user,  and its fast,

Comment: Why do you need to load such a large amount of data into a datatable at once? In general, filtering large amounts of data should be implemented in the database server.